# Javascript Open Window in Loop

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript for loop to open window in different tabs but when i checked one of the code from web its only opening the last link.

Please find the below jsfiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ag2H5/

Thanks,

Comment: Add target="_blank" to anchor tag

Comment: If am giving _blank tag to anchor tag still its not opening.

Comment: <a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg" target="_blank">Click Here</a><br />.

Comment: Ok got that actually popup in browser was blocked. Thank u very much for the clarification. if u could post that anwer i can upvote you.

Comment: Yes sure........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

Attribute Values

- **_blank**    Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
- **_self** Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
- **_parent**   Opens the linked document in the parent frame
- **_top**  Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
- **framename** Opens the linked document in a named frame

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, I think your problem is that the browser is preventing more windows to be opened.

In chrome (for example) after you click the button, you will have to `Allow` all pop-ups (through the icon on the right, inside the address bar), and then... next time you press the button, it will actually open all your 4 (n) tabs.

> Not sure this should be on the Salesforce Channel though...